# Convert If-Else Statement to MIPS Assembly Code

Tags: assembly, mips

Assume that the variables `f, g, h, i, and j` are assigned to registers `$s0, $s1, $s2, $s3, and $s4`, respectively. Assume that the base address of the `arrays A` is in register `$s6.`

```
if (f==g)
     A[4] = f+g;
else if (f == h)
             A[4]  = A[h] + f;
        else
             A[i] = g-h;
```

I'm trying to convert the above C++ code into MIPS. Here is what I've done:

```
.data


.text
main:
    beq $s0,$s1,if #if $s0 = $s1 go to then
    beq $s0,$s2,elseif
    
    #else statement
    sub $t0, $s1, $s2 # $t0 = g - h
    sll $t1, $s3, 2 # Calculating offset
    add $t2, $t1, $s6 # $t2 = offset + base
    sw $t3, 0($t2)
                    
    if: #if statement
        add $t0, $s0, $s1 # $t0 = f + g
        sw $t0, 16($s6) # A[4]
        j exit #jump to exit
    
    elseif: #elseif statement
        sll $t1,$s2,2 # Calculating offset
        add $t2,$t1,$s6 #t2 = offset + base
        lw $t3,0($t2) # t3 = A[h] 
        add $t0,$t3,$s0 # $t0 = A[h] + f
    
    exit:
```

Can someone take a look if it is corrected, please?
Thank you so much

Comment: _"Can someone take a look if it is corrected"_ That should be easy enough for you to verify yourself by using one of the available MIPS simulators (QtSPIM, MARS, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct.  In the case that f != g and f != h it will execute the proper else clause, but then continue on to execute the first then clause.  You should run it in a simulator to see.

Further, there is no store instruction for the `elseif:` section, so it doesn't translate.